# Fisher's Exact test on a 2x4 contingency table

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

Can you do a Fisher's Exact test on a 2x4 contingency table? If so, what is the most appropriate way to interpret the results?

I'm working with a dataset where I'm trying to compare whether people who are employed in two different occupations experience different levels of anger within the past 30 days (e.g. "ever angry" = experienced anger in the past 30 days).

I determined that I should use a fisher's exact test after running the code below and finding that at least one of the expected cell values < 5.

```
chisq.test(stat_test_table)$expected

         Ever Angry   Never Angry        Don't Know  Other
```

Occupation 1 1020.8987     6399.212        12.260593   283.62839
Occupation 2 228.1013      1429.788        2.739407    63.37161

So, then I ran the following code, but I'm not sure how to interpret the results. Is is correct to say that we can reject the null hypothesis and conclude that occupation impacts level of anger across all categories (i.e whether you're ever angry, never angry, don't know, or other)?

```
fisher.test(stat_test_table)
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  stat_test_table
p-value = 1.007e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```